# Does the glide slope flag detect percent of modulation (80%)?

Tags: flight-instruments, instrument-procedures, ils

Please advise if the glideslope flag validates that the received frequency is being modulated at nominal 80% or 40% for a localizer.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment, but it's a bit long.

From ICAO Chicago Convention [annex 10, vol 1](https://www.bazl.admin.ch/dam/bazl/de/dokumente/Fachleute/Regulationen_und_Grundlagen/icao-annex/icao_annex_10_aeronauticaltelecommunicationsvolumei-radionavigat.pdf.download.pdf/icao_annex_10_aeronauticaltelecommunicationsvolumei-radionavigat.pdf):

> 2.3 Alarm conditions for ILS airborne equipment
>
> 2.3.1 Ideally, a receiver alarm system such as a visual flag should warn a pilot
> of any unacceptable malfunctioning conditions which might
> arise within either the ground or airborne equipments. The extent to
> which such an ideal may be satisfied is specified below.
>
> ...
>
> 2.3.3 The alarm system should indicate to the pilot and to any other airborne system which may be utilizing the localizer and glide path
> data, the existence of any of the following conditions:
>
> ...
>
> b) the percentage modulation of either the 90 Hz or 150 Hz signal
> reduction to zero with the other maintained at its normal 20 per cent
> and 40 per cent modulation respectively for the localizer and glide
> path;
>
> *Note.— It is expected that the localizer alarm occur when either the
> 90 Hz or 150 Hz modulation is reduced to 10 per cent with the other
> maintained at its normal 20 per cent. It is expected that the glide
> path alarm occur when either the 90 Hz or 150 Hz modulation is reduced
> to 20 per cent with the other maintained at its normal 40 per cent.*

Glide path receiving equipment operational standards are detailed in [RTCA DO-192](https://www.atmmasterplan.eu/data/standards/3117481) and [EUROCAE ED-47B](https://www.atmmasterplan.eu/data/standards/3117498)